# installing car radio - cords issue

Tags: audio, wiring

I bought a simple radio, and i am trying to install it.
From the new radio the following wires exist:
speakers: 2*grey, 2*pruple. 2*blue, 2*green.
Yellow - go to battery
Black - go to ground
red (acc) - go to ignition
blue - power antena

So i went to the car, disassembled the current radio, exposed all the wires, and connected the new ones to existing ones.. all the color matched, in my previous installation there were additional wires:
Yellow with black stroke on it - Ill (as illuminus)
Blue - Power source control
Yellow with white stroke - i dont know what is this.
And ofcourse the black wire to connect the radio antena.

I connected all the wires, failed to connect My new radio blue wire () antena power) - where am i supposed to connect it ?
When i start the car, i only see red light coming from the radio, but it does not start, i push the on button, nothing happens.
Did i do something wrong ?

[image: New radio]

[image: current wires]

[image: what is this source control wire ?]

[image]

Comment: Did you actually plug in the antenna? I looks like it's hanging in one o the pictures? This is important with some radios and their proper workings. Also, does your vehicle have a power antenna? If not, the blue wire would not be used.

Answer (score 3):

OK, so we figured it out.
When i was trying to connect the car to a computer. The computer did not start. A fuse was burned.
What i did wrong in the first place ?

In the radio there was a  blue "power antena" wire, And from the car radio unit there was a blue wire "Source control power", i connected them (i thought blue goes to blue) - well i was wrong.  In my car there is no use to power antena (its always opened).
So we replaced the fuse and I did not connect the blue wires this time.
Now everything is fine. I just connected Yellow to yellow, red to red, black to black and speakers to speakers.

**My conclusion** - if you are not sure if the cables are suppose to be connected  - dont connect them :)